# Dart: generic type extending a class with generic types in it

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

I have a class defined like this:

`abstract class QuestionPageBaseState<T extends Question<dynamic, dynamic>> {...`

The class `Question` is defined like this:

`abstract class Question<T, U> {...`

is it possible to replace the `dynamic` with a generic type like this?:

`abstract class QuestionPageBaseState<T extends Question<U, V>> {...`

When I try I get this error:
`The name 'U' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see the error because the compiler doesn't know where the generic type comes from and thinks it's a concrete class (such as int, double, String...); however, it's not.

You can achieve it specifying `U` and `V` as type parameters to `QuestionPageBaseState` which will pass them to `Question`:

```dart
abstract class QuestionPageBaseState<T extends Question<U, V>, U, V> {}
```

Comment: Amazing, exactly what I was looking for!
I couldn't find any documentation with such a case, do you know if there is any doc somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any documentation, but there are a few issues regarding this on github. You may find some useful examples provided by Dart team.